# Where are the GPIO pins on Digilent Basys 3 FPGA Board?

Tags: fpga, gpio

I do not have a great understanding of electronics circuits and their fabrication. So please pardon me for the noob-ness of this post.

In one article that I am reading now, they have attached wires to 3.3V general-purpose I/O pins on the Digilent Basys 3 FPGA Board. Can anyone please point me to which pins [on the board](https://digilent.com/reference/_media/reference/programmable-logic/basys-3/basys3_rm.pdf) they are referring to?

Comment: If don't say which article you refer to, or the article really does not say which pins are used, how can anyone know? On the other hand, does it matter which pins are used, as long as the connections can be made to them? The PMOD connectors do contain IO.

Comment: I can't share the article, it's confidential. Probably I couldn't ask the right question. Apologies for that. 

I am curious to know how electrical connections to those GPIO pins are made on that specific board. It houses Artix 7 FPGA which has got minimum of 150 pins (https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds180_7Series_Overview.pdf) even for the lowest-end model. I want to know how those FPGA pins are exposed through the dev board so that they can be attached to.

Comment: So doesn't the link you gave already explain that? For example PMOD connector A pin 1 is FPGA pin J1.

Comment: Even if it does, I didn't realize that. How do you know the pin mapping? Which section of the document I should look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sections each describe a subsystem and describes where each pin of the subsystem is connected to on the FPGA, such as buttons and LEDs. If you are interested in external connectivity, look at the PMOD section.